# Maximum table/query size limits for Postgres Foreign Data Wrapper (FDW)?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, postgres-fdw

Are there limits to the PostgreSQL Foreign Data Wrapper extension? 
i.e. is there some maximum size of source table (or schema/database) that can be set up as a Foreign Table via FDW? We are using Postgres 10.6

We've occasionally run into situations where it seems to fail with tables that cross some size threshold (~8GB) but I'm unsure if this is something we can tweak, or perhaps a limitation on the source db end. (In this example the source table is in Redshift.)

The error message that comes back is: 
`ERROR:  exceeded the maximum size allowed for the total set of cursor data: 8000MB.`

EDIT: Discovered the source of the problem - the size of this particular Redshift instance has this cursor size limit. They are listed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/declare.html#declare-constraints

We ended up filtering the results to make the FDW more workable.

Comment: Can you give example of the error message/sql used when the error occurs. I use somw large redshift FDWs and have not hit a problem yet

Comment: How are you running PostgreSQL? On an EC2 instance? RDS? Aurora?

Comment: Error message added - hitting a max size for cursor data. And our Postgres instance is running on RDS.